# Using ROLLUP and GROUPING SETS to format results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to learn the `ROLLUP` and `GROUPING SETS` operators in SQL Server 2008 R2. My table looks like this:

```
+-------+---------+------------+------+-------+----------+------+
| EmpID | EmpName | StartDate  | Type | Units | Account  | Dist |
+-------+---------+------------+------+-------+----------+------+
| 11111 | Alice   | 2015-09-04 | SD20 | 0.500 | 560.2200 |  100 |
| 11111 | Alice   | 2015-09-08 | CCS  | 1.330 | 9P0.6010 |   38 |
| 11111 | Alice   | 2015-09-08 | CCS  | 2.170 | 010.9055 |   62 |
| 11111 | Alice   | 2015-09-10 | SD20 | 0.500 | LP0.3002 |  100 |
| 11111 | Alice   | 2015-09-14 | SD20 | 0.500 | LP0.3002 |  100 |
| 11111 | Alice   | 2015-09-17 | SD20 | 1.000 | LP0.P303 |  100 |
| 11111 | Alice   | 2015-09-18 | SD20 | 1.000 | 600.2200 |  100 |
| 11111 | Alice   | 2015-09-24 | SD20 | 1.000 | LP0.3002 |  100 |
| 11111 | Alice   | 2015-09-25 | SD20 | 1.000 | LP0.3002 |  100 |
| 11111 | Alice   | 2015-09-29 | SD20 | 1.000 | LP0.3002 |  100 |
| 33333 | Carol   | 2015-09-03 | SD20 | 1.000 | 9P0.PP10 |  100 |
| 33333 | Carol   | 2015-09-04 | SD20 | 0.200 | 600.6P62 |   20 |
| 33333 | Carol   | 2015-09-04 | SD20 | 0.800 | 600.6P62 |   80 |
| 33333 | Carol   | 2015-09-25 | SD20 | 1.000 | P50.2100 |  100 |
+-------+---------+------------+------+-------+----------+------+
```

I want EmpID and EmpName to display once per employee, the Units to be subtotaled by Type, and to be ordered by EmpID, Type, Account, like so:

```
+-------+---------+----------------+-------+----------+
| EmpID | EmpName |      Type      | Units | Account  |
+-------+---------+----------------+-------+----------+
| 11111 | Alice   |                |       |          |
|       |         | CCS            | 2.17  | 010.9055 |
|       |         | CCS            | 1.33  | 9P0.6010 |
|       |         |       Subtotal | 3.5   |          |
|       |         | SD20           | 0.5   | 560.2200 |
|       |         | SD20           | 1     | 600.2200 |
|       |         | SD20           | 4     | LP0.3002 |
|       |         | SD20           | 1     | LP0.P303 |
|       |         |       Subtotal | 6.5   |          |
| 33333 | Carol   |                |       |          |
|       |         | SD20           | 1     | 600.6P62 |
|       |         | SD20           | 1     | 9P0.PP10 |
|       |         | SD20           | 1     | P50.2100 |
|       |         |       Subtotal | 3     |          |
+-------+---------+----------------+-------+----------+
```

Here's my query

```
select 
case
    when Account is null and Type is null then cast(EmpID as varchar(10))
    else ''
end SubEIN, 
case
    when Account is null and Type is null then EmpName 
    else ''
end SubName, 
case
    when Account is null and Type is not null then 'Subtotal:'
    else isnull(Type, '')
end Type, 
case
    when Account is null and Type is null then ''
    else cast(Units as varchar(10)) 
end Units, 
isnull(Account, '')
from (
    select EmpID, EmpName, Type, sum(Units) AS Units, Account
    from mytable
    group by grouping sets ((EmpID, EmpName), (EmpID, EmpName, Type), (EmpID, EmpName, Account, Type))
) x
order by x.EmpName, x.Type, x.Units, x.Account
```

Can I use the `ROLLUP` and/or `GROUPING SETS` operators to get what I want instead of all the `CASE` expressions?

Comment: Check: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/387777

Answer (score 0):

I believe the GROUP BY WITH CUBE operator will get you close to the end goal.   With this approach, you have the option to filter down the rows or change how null values are presented.

```
select 
    EmpID, 
    EmpName, 
    [Type], 
    Units, 
    Account
from 
    (   
        select 
            EmpID, 
            EmpName, 
            [Type], 
            sum(Units) AS Units, 
            Account
        from mytable
        group by EmpID, EmpName, [Type], Account with CUBE
    ) s
where s.yourfilter
```

Link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175939(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You kind-of expect too much from ROLLUP I think - here is my suggestion sample, I couldn't get rid of CASE-s entirely, but the result look like what you are aiming for:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (
    EmpID INT,
    EmpName VARCHAR(100),
    StartDate DATE,
    [Type] VARCHAR(10),
    Units DECIMAL(10, 3),
    Account VARCHAR(100),
    Dist INT
);

INSERT INTO
    @Data
VALUES
    (11111, 'Alice', '2015-09-04', 'SD20', 0.500, '560.2200', 100),
    (11111, 'Alice', '2015-09-08', 'CCS',  1.330, '9P0.6010',  38),
    (11111, 'Alice', '2015-09-08', 'CCS',  2.170, '010.9055',  62),
    (11111, 'Alice', '2015-09-10', 'SD20', 0.500, 'LP0.3002', 100),
    (11111, 'Alice', '2015-09-14', 'SD20', 0.500, 'LP0.3002', 100),
    (11111, 'Alice', '2015-09-17', 'SD20', 1.000, 'LP0.P303', 100),
    (11111, 'Alice', '2015-09-18', 'SD20', 1.000, '600.2200', 100),
    (11111, 'Alice', '2015-09-24', 'SD20', 1.000, 'LP0.3002', 100),
    (11111, 'Alice', '2015-09-25', 'SD20', 1.000, 'LP0.3002', 100),
    (11111, 'Alice', '2015-09-29', 'SD20', 1.000, 'LP0.3002', 100),
    (33333, 'Carol', '2015-09-03', 'SD20', 1.000, '9P0.PP10', 100),
    (33333, 'Carol', '2015-09-04', 'SD20', 0.200, '600.6P62',  20),
    (33333, 'Carol', '2015-09-04', 'SD20', 0.800, '600.6P62',  80),
    (33333, 'Carol', '2015-09-25', 'SD20', 1.000, 'P50.2100', 100)


SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN RN = 0 THEN OrigEmpID
        ELSE NULL 
        END AS EmpID,
    CASE
        WHEN RN = 0 THEN EmpName
        ELSE NULL 
        END AS EmpName,
    CASE
        WHEN RN = 0 THEN NULL
        WHEN RN = 3 THEN 'Subtotal' 
        ELSE [OrigType] 
        END AS [Type],
    Units,
    Account
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        0 AS RN,
        EmpID AS OrigEmpID, 
        EmpName,
        cast(NULL AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [OrigType],
        cast(NULL AS DECIMAL(10,3)) AS Units,
        cast(NULL AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Account
    FROM
        @Data

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CASE WHEN Account IS NULL THEN 3 ELSE 2 END RN,
        EmpID AS OrigEmpID, 
        EmpName, 
        [Type] AS [OrigType],
        sum(Units) AS Units, 
        Account
    FROM
        @Data
    GROUP BY 
        EmpID, EmpName, [Type], ROLLUP(Account)
) data
ORDER BY
    OrigEmpID, [OrigType], RN, Account
```